# How to call a .NET Core API from Angular which takes a model in its parameter?

Tags: angular, ajax, typescript, asp.net-core, http

Please help, I want to get a list from a .NET Core API, I keep getting an error 415, media type not supported.

In the `service.ts` file I have:

```
getProductList(listObj:any) {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}GetFilteredList`,listObj);
}
```

In the component.ts file

```
products:any= [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getProductList(this.products).subscribe({
      next:(res)=>{
        if(res.status){
          this.products = res.record;
        }
      }
    })
```

API takes a model which has 8 properties as parameter

```
public ResultModel ProductList(ProductModel model) {
```

```
{
    "subCategoryID": 0,
    "categoryID": 0,
    "key 3" : ""
}
```

API call returns

```
    "status": true,
    "record": [
        {
            "key1": 0,
            "key 2": 62,
            "key 3" : "string val"
            .
            .

        },
        {
            "categoryID": 0,
            "saleListingID": 61,
            "key 3" : "string val"
        },
```

I want to show res.record in the component.html file

```
<ul *ngFor="let product of products">
    <li> {{product.subCategoryID}} </li>
    <li> {{product.categoryID}} </li>
    <li> {{product.price}} </li>
    <li> {{product.country}} </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are sending an array `products:any= []` but your API expects the parameter which is a `ProductModel model` object.

Comment: @YongShun and how do i send a model as parameter in api call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your http method is Get, You can add `[FromQuery]` attribute to bind value from route in backend action, Please refer to this simple demo:

**ProductModel**

```
public class ProductModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

**APi**

```
[HttpGet]
public List<ResultModel> Get([FromQuery]ProductModel model)
{
      //........
        List<ResultModel> result = new List<ResultModel>()
        {
            new ResultModel()
            {
                subCategoryID = 1,
                categoryID = 1,
                price = 10, 
                country = "UK"
            },
            new ResultModel()
            {
                subCategoryID = 2,
                categoryID = 2,
                price = 20,
                country = "USA"
            },
            new ResultModel()
            {
                subCategoryID = 3,
                categoryID = 3,
                price = 46,
                country = "CN"
            }
        };

        return result;
}
```

**Angular**

```
let params = new HttpParams({ fromObject: {Id: "1", Name: "Jack",Age:"22"}})
    this.client.get('https://localhost:7273/api/Test',{params:params}).subscribe(console.log)
```

**Gif Demo**

[image]

From above Gif, backend bind value successfully.